# custom object has xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> for some developers and not others. Any idea how to fix?

Tags: ide, metadata-api

A new fun sync problem popped up today, some developers when they sync with a custom object get this:

```
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Others get this:

```
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
```

A new tug of war item to add to the list.

Any ideas why some would get the namespace stuff  when they sync and others dont? All users operating off the same sandbox type.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration for the xsi prefix will only be added if the xsi namespace is required, when you get the xsi prefix you should find that somewhere in the document its being used, and when you don't get it, its not being used. You'll have to look at the specific element that using the xsi namespace to determine why its there.

One difference might be related to the API version you're using, make sure everyone is using a consistent API version. (and therefore the same version of the IDE plugin)

Comment: Yes agree, is it the same object for different developers or the different objects? If its the later its possible a feature your using in some objects requires the XML markup to utilise xsi type.

Comment: yes, its the same object, thanks for the hint, I found this:   <customTabListAdditionalFields xsi:nil="true"/> - within the search layout. How would that have been added? What would someone do to the server to trigger that being added?

Comment: Old post, I know... but since I saw this...   I have seen the xsi:nil being added if you had added a field to the search layout but when deleted the field. SFDC deletes the field but fails to clean up every reference to it. So, you will see this null reference. Two workarounds: either edit and re-save (no need to make any changes) to the Search layout   or just handle/ ignore the xsi:nil and migrate everything else.